# Understanding what exactly neural network is predicting in documentation example (MNIST)

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I've taken a quick course in neural networks to better understand them and now I'm trying them out for myself in R. I'm following [this](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/getting_started.html) documentation of Keras.

**The way I understand what is happening:**

We are inputting a series of images and transforming these images to numerical matrices based on the arrangement of the pixels and colors in those pixels. We then build a neural network model to learn the pattern of these arrangements, depending on the classification (0 to 9). We then use the model to predict which class an image belongs to. I'll be honest and admit I'm not entirely sure what y_train and x_train is. I simply see it as one training and one validation set so I'm not sure what the difference between x and y is.

**My question:**

I've followed the steps to the T and the model runs fine and the predictions look like they do in the documentation. Ultimately, the prediction looks like this:[image]

I take this to mean that observation 1 in x_test is predicted to be a category 7.

However, looking at x_test it looks like this: [image]

There is a 0 in every column and row, also if I scroll further down. This is where I get confused. I'm also not sure how I view the original images to view for myself how well they are predicting  them. I would eventually like to draw a number myself in paint or so and then see if the model can predict it, but for that I need to first understand what is going on. I feel I am close but I just need a little nudge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you read more about the input and output layer's dimensions, that would help.

In your example:
Input layer: 
A single training example of image has two dimensions 28*28, which is then converted to a single vector of dimension 784. This acts as the input layer for the neural network. 
So for `m` training examples, your input layer will have dimensions `(m, 784)`. Analogically speaking (to traditional ML systems), you can imagine that each pixel of an image is converted into a feature (or x1, x2, ... x784), and your training set is a dataframe with `m` rows and `784` columns, which is then fed into neural network to compute `y_hat = f(x1,x2,x3,...x784)`.

Output layer:
As an output for our neural network, we want it to predict which number it is from `0 to 9`. So for a single training example, the output layer has dimension 10, representing each number from 0 to 9 and for `n` testing examples the output layer would be a matrix with dimension `n*10`.
Our `y` is a vector of length `n` which would be something like `[1,7,8,2,.....]` containing true value for each testing example. But to match the dimension of output layer, the `y` vector's dimension are converted using one-hot encoding. Imagine a length  10 vector, representing number 7 by putting 1 at 7th place and rest of the positions zeros something like `[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]`.

So in your question, if you wish to see the original image, you should be able to see it before reshaping the training examples with something like `image(mnist$test$x[1, , ]`

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

**y_train** are the labels and **x_train** is the training data, so images in this example. You need to use some kind of plotting library to plot x'es. In this example you probably are not expected to input your own drawings and if you want you would need to preprocess them in the same way as in MNIST and pass them to the model.

Comment: If I'd plot the x's in the data it would just be 0. There are only 0's. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer?